# xpath query seem to be failing

Tags: xml, xpath

Can someone tell me the reason for the failure of this
xpath query:

```
//Pages/*[(name() = 'Home')  or following-sibling::Home]
```

on this xml structure:

```
<Pages>
    <copyright>me inc. 2015,</copyright>
    <author>Me</author>
    <lastUpdate>2/1/1999</lastUpdate>

    <Home>--------------------</Home>
    <About>--------------------</About>
    <Contact>------------------</Contact> 
</Pages>
```

only returned copyright element, which is against
my targets (To grab all element between Pages and home. 
that is: copyright, author, lastUpdate and entire Home).
or am i doing it wrongly ?

```html
public function fetchAsArray( $pathToRecord, $conversionOption = array() ) {
    if( $pathToRecord == null){
         $this->Err['code'] = ERR_EMPTY_XPATH_QUERY;      
         $this->Err['msg'] = " Specified path to an xml file is non-existent "; 
           return false;
    }
        
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($this->xmlObj);
    $result = $xml->xpath( $pathToRecord );        //unknown node handle 
        
    if ($result === false) { 
       $this->parseError();                   //To return xml Error code
       return false ; 
    }
        
    if (empty($result)) { 
       return NO_RECORD_FOUND;
     }  

   return $this->strToArray($result[0]->saveXML());       //strToArray() is here: https://gist.github.com/laiello/8189351
}
```

```html
/*
     inside myXMLManager::fetchAsArray(), i did this:

     foreach( $result as $val ) {echo $xml->saveXML($val);}
     
     returned Error was, Warning: SimpleXMLElement::saveXML( ): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
     lib\myXMLManager.php on line 205.

     next, changing $result to result[0] in the same foreach returned null.
     lastly, just doing var_dump($result[0]); returned null, while 
     var_dump($result) returned:
     
     array (size=4)
     0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[8]
     1 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[9]
     2 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]
     3 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[11]

    null

       whats' wrong ? or could it be from the call to strToArray() henceforth ?
*/​
```

Comment: How are you checking the returned nodeset? Which XPathe engine are you using? On my side, your query returned the `copyright`, `author`, `lastUpdate` and `Home` nodes - exactly as expected. (oh, and your query can be made slightly shorter: `//Pages/*[self::Home or following-sibling::Home]`)

Comment: Your XPath does return copyright, author, lastUpdate and Home: http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=3dfef61e-3bfc-446d-b8ad-8712434a1d28-xpath

Comment: @OsagieOdigie maybe, you show the code than 3rd time create the same question. This path is OK, the problem in implementation

Comment: actually it was done through a call to function fetchasArray()
which is resident in my XMLManager objet. see it above. then i issued a print_r() to double check, and it failed

Comment: your $result[0] is the  first result of xpath ? try to show all item of nodes list

Comment: something like `foreach($result as $r)  echo $xml->saveXML($r);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '<root><Pages>
    <copyright>me inc. 2015,</copyright>
    <author>Me</author>
    <lastUpdate>2/1/1999</lastUpdate>

    <Home>--------------------</Home>
    <About>--------------------</About>
    <Contact>------------------</Contact> 
</Pages></root>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$result = $xml->xpath('//Pages/*[(name() = "Home")  or following-sibling::Home]');        
    if ($result === false) { 
       $this->parseError();                   //To return xml Error code
       return false ; 
    }

    if (empty($result)) { 
       return NO_RECORD_FOUND;
     }  

   foreach($result as $r) echo $r->getName()."\n";
```

result

```
copyright
author
lastUpdate
Home
```

Comment: i've found the problem. what happened was the line:  return $this->strToArray($result[0]->saveXML());  passed <copyright>me inc. 2015,</copyright> to function strToArray() and returned immediately to caller. so,  funcftion strToArray() didint border itself with other passed in string. i must accept that i am stupid, and must appreciate you for your assistance. God bless.

Comment: I glad that you found the solution. Good luck!